# JQuery add placeholder value to a specific div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a placeholder value and load it inside #placeholder-value". How can I do this with Jquery?

Thank you!

```
<input name="input-name" type="text" id="input-id" class="searchBox" placeholder="Some text"> 
<div id="placeholder-value"></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide some HTML/CSS or include things you have already tried? You will get down voted otherwise.

Comment: A place holder in a div is known as text.

Comment: `$('div').attr({'id':$('input').attr('placeholder')});` should work

Comment: On second thought: `$('div').html($('input').attr('placeholder'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example of how to add an `<input>` placeholder into a `<div>` when the page loads:

**HTML**

```
<div class="write"></div>
<input placeholder="Hello World" type="text" class="read" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.write').text($('.read').attr('placeholder'));
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bP95A/)**

**--EDIT--**

Here is the correct JQuery for your provided code:

```
$('#placeholder-value').text($('#input-id').attr('placeholder'));
```